# How are class fields treated in an ASP.NET web form class?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, viewstate

Consider a web form (aspx) wth an associated codefile (aspx.cs).

In the codefile, for instance, we have the following:

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page {

   int myint;
   string mystring;

   public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      ...
      if (!this.IsPostBack) {
         this.myint = 2;
         this.mystring = "Hello";
      }
      ...
   }

}
```

Can I expect to have the two variables everytime the page is posted back? I mean: are page class fields kept as part of the web form state?

Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, these objects would be disposed at the end of the [Page-Lifecycle.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)
If you want to persist them in ViewState you have to [add them to it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Objects that need to be stored in ViewState must be [serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

**Storing Simple Data Types in the ViewState**

> Like most types of state management in
>   ASP.NET, view state relies on a
>   dictionary collection, where each item
>   is indexed with a unique string name.
>   For example, consider this code:

```
ViewState["ViewStateVariableName"] = 1;
```

> This places the value 1 (or rather, an
>   integer that contains the value 1)
>   into the ViewState collection and
>   gives it the descriptive name
>   ViewStateVariable. If there is
>   currently no item with the name
>   ViewStateVariable, a new item will be
>   added automatically. If there is
>   already an item indexed under this
>   name, it will be replaced.
>
> You can access this variable anywhere
>   within the page/control where the
>   viewstate variable has been added.
>   When retrieving a value, you use the
>   key name.

```
int number = (int) ViewState["ViewStateVariable"];
```

> You also need to cast the retrieved
>   value to the appropriate data type.
>   This is because the ViewState
>   collection stores all items as generic
>   objects which also give you the
>   flexibility to store any type of basic
>   data types in it. In fact, you can
>   even store your custom objects in the
>   view state.

**Storing Objects in View State**

> You can store your own objects in view
>   state just as easily as you store
>   numeric and string types. However, to
>   store an item in view state, ASP.NET
>   must be able to convert it into a
>   stream of bytes so that it can be
>   added to the hidden input field in the
>   page. This process is called
>   serialization. If your objects aren't
>   serializable (and by default they
>   aren't), you'll receive an error
>   message when you attempt to place them
>   in view state.

- http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/ViewState-In-ASP.NET.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188774.aspx

Comment: Tim I guess you're becoming my .NET GURU!!! Thank you very much for being always so verbose (in the good way) and clear in your answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not. They are not persisted to viewstate.

In order to persist them, you need to make them properties that store their values in ViewState, like so:

```
public string MyString
{
    get { return (string) ViewState["MyString"];
    set { ViewState["MyString"] = value; }
}
```